# Visual C++ 2010 won't create an .exe file

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging

I've recently been learning some code for DirectX 10, and everything was working fine and compiling with no errors. Then I added some additional code to my program and suddenly I keep getting the error message "Unable to start program 'File directory' The system cannot find the file specified. It was working fine before I added some additional code, but still won't work after I've removed that code. I've tried the answers given by other people such as to make sure I'm looking in the correct Debug folder and to make sure the Output directory is correct and both cases didn't help. I don't know why, but this same error has happened on other projects I had started and I never figured out how to fix them. Please help, I'd really like to get back to coding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the Error List window.  Fix your mistakes.

Comment: I've fixed the issue. I changed the Output and Intermediate directories to Debug, this seems to have fixed the issue. Why, I don't know, but I'm not complaining. Thanks for the attempted help. :)